# How do I scroll a Gridview in Android, so icons will appear?

Tags: android

I want to scroll the screen vertically in a grid view. As I scroll downwards, icons should appear.

I implemented it in a view flipper which was quite easy. I searched in Google, but couldn't find much help.

Comment: Try to elaborate a little bit more your question please

Comment: Actually I have tow arrow keys in my screen. By clicking on it, icons should go upwards or downwards.  In gridview, we can scroll only one element at a time whereas I have to scroll one row at a time on clicking the forward/backward button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `android:smoothScrollbar="true"` for your Gridview in the layout file, then it becomes scrollable automatically, if the number of grid items exceed the screen size.